# I can't post date in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I can't insert date here. My table was:

```
CREATE TABLE salary
(
    emp_id int NOT NULL,
    basic int,
    net_salary double,
    salary_date date,
    FOREIGN KEY(emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
)
```

When I gave:

```
INSERT INTO `salary`(`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary`, `salary_date`) 
VALUES (121,5000, ,2019-06-21)
```

it shows an error message:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2019-06-21)' at line 1

N.B.: I am not putting net_salary as 0/null because I had made a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW calc_salary AS
SELECT basic
FROM salary
WHERE (basic+0.45*basic-0.09*basic-0.15*basic) = net_salary
```

i.e. net_salary is to be calculated from basic.

Comment: Date literals in MySQL take single quotes, so use `'2019-06-21'`

Comment: Also the insert seams to be missing a value for net_salary column?

Comment: There's a value missing in the VALUES list, between the two commas. And as TB says, we need to use single quotes around date literals. The view definition is very odd. That doesn't have anything to do with the INSERT. It's not at all clear why the view is returning only one column, and why we're restricting the rows returned to the condition given in the where clause. (I suspect that we aren't understanding how a view works; one thing it doesn't do is calculate values of columns for an insert. If we wanted a database object to do the calculation, seems like we'd want a function or a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value for net_salary is missing, and we need to use single quote around date literals. To get rid of the syntax errors, it would need to like this:

```
INSERT INTO `salary` (`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary`, `salary_date`) 
VALUES (121,5000,NULL,'2019-06-21')
                 ^^^^ ^          ^
```

If we want to calculate a value for `net_salary`, we could do that in the INSERT statement.

If the condition shown in the WHERE clause view:

```
(basic+0.45*basic-0.09*basic-0.15*basic) = net_salary
```

actually represents the formula we use to calculate `net_salary` from `basic`,

then we could express that as an assignment:

```
net_salary := ( basic*1.0 ) + ( basic*+0.45 ) + ( basic*-0.09 ) + ( basic*-0.15 )
```

we can factor that and rewrite that into an equivalent expression:

```
net_salary :=  basic * ( (1.0) + (0.45) + (-0.09) + (-0.15) )
```

With that, we could do something like this to provide a value for `net_salary` for the row being inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `salary` (`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary`, `salary_date`) 
VALUES (121,5000, 5000 * ( (1.0) + (0.45) + (-0.09) + (-0.15) ) ,'2019-06-21')
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But if the value of `net_salary` is always calculated that way, based on the value of  `basic`, it seems redundant to store that as a column, since We could calculate the value whenever we need it. For example:

```
 SELECT s.emp_id 
      , s.basic
      , s.basic * ( (1.0) + (0.45) + (-0.09) + (-0.15) ) AS calc_net_salary
      , s.salary_date
   FROM salary
  WHERE ...
```

If we do that, then we could drop the `net_salary` column from the table.

But if we do have to store that calculated value in a column, then we could have `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers calculate the value for us.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER salary_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON salary
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SET NEW.net_salary := NEW.basic * ( (1.0) + (0.45) + (-0.09) + (-0.15) );
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @UtshabKumarGhosh Using a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) is most likely better suited and more easy  `ALTER TABLE ...  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (( basic*1.0 ) + ( basic*+0.45 ) + ( basic*-0.09 ) + ( basic*-0.15 ))` to use vs using two triggers see [alter manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)